# Firebase - Get parent of child which value is unknown

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Schema]

I need to get child (Child I Need in code) but I don't know how to access it, if I know ID of parent which is saved as his child. Also I need to check everyone in group and get their *Child I need*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do :

```
 DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getChild("ID I know").getChild("request");
 dbRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        // Here you will iterate over all the values whose ID you wont know
                        Map<String, Object> values = dataSnapshot.getValue();
                        // Iterate over the values and for each value check if it has the child you need in it
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        // on error
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Well It was just one more object in path. Working for all day make me mad :D. Anyway thank you